# Notepad ++ replace empty cell white spaces with NA

Tags: notepad++

I would like to replace empty cells with NA in Notepad ++
The empty cells are not showing here, but I would like to fill in the empty spaces with NA.

Sample data set:

15876346,71F,70152731459,H,2.3,6,14,31

18334617,82F,7015273698,C,1.2, , ,21

42190557,01F,7015273,C, , ,21,57

Desired output:

15876346,71F,70152731459,H,2.3,6,14,31

18334617,82F,7015273698,C,1.2,NA ,NA ,21

42190557,01F,7015273,C,NA ,NA,21,57

Comment: are they always space separated ? then try replace with an regexp [ ](?=[ ]) an replace it with space and NA

Comment: Please, format properly and add expected result.

Comment: Isn't just a global search-and-replace of `,,` with `,NA,` going to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=,)\h*(?=,)`
- Replace with: `NA`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=,)      # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a comma before
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(?=,)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have a comma after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]